# Foreach calls MoveNext in Enumerator first, Current second

Tags: c#, foreach, enumerator

My issue is basically in order of the functions/property called. I have a custom linked list, circular one. So I made a custom enumenator and all. The issue is, the foreach cycle actually calls the `MoveNext()` method of enumerator first, therefore moving from the actual first Node of the cycle to the second node, which is kind of bad if you want to have your items in actual order.

Question is, am I doing something wrong, and if not, how to compensate for this?

Code of `Enumerator` is simple as can be. This, basically:

```
class EnumeratorLinkedList : IEnumerator<Node>
{
    private Node current;
    private Node first;
    private bool didWeMove;

    public EnumeratorSpojovySeznam(Node current)
    {
        this.current = current;
        this.first = current;
        didWeMove = false;
    }

    public Node Current => current;

    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current => Current;

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if ((didWeMove == true && current == first)) return false;
        current = current.Next;
        didWeMove = true;
        return true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how it is supposed to be according to the language specification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-foreach-statement

Comment: I would recommend to take a look at the implementation of the `LinkedList<T>` enumerator for ideas how to implement your own enumerator correctly: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,462 (Short version is: you need one more member to hold the currently referenced element of the enumerator, which will be "1 ahead" of `current`)

Comment: @UnholySheep I am aware that this is expected behaviour for foreach cycle, merely asking if my Enumerator was badly written or, if not, how to otherwise run around it. I will give this a look.

Answer (score 3):

Do you consider using [`C# iterators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators) to implement enumerator for your circular `LinkedList`? If you do, it is very simple. `Iterators` provide convenient and easy way to implement enumerators.

Here is how enumerator can be implemented for your circular `LinkedList`:

```
class LinkedList : IEnumerable<Node>
{
    private Node first;

    public IEnumerator<Node> GetEnumerator()
    {
        // Check if LinkedList is empty.
        // If it is empty we immediately break enumeration.
        if (first == null)
            yield break;

        // Here goes logic for enumerating circular LinkedList.
        Node current = first;

        do
        {
            yield return current;
            current = current.Next;
        } while (current != first);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

As you can see an implementation using `iterator` is more straightforward and intuitive.

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bwsIQ3) that demonstrates usage of `iterators`.